# ¿Cómo puedo Hacer una función que contenga otras funciones?

Tags: php, laravel, funciones, programación-funcional

Lo que quiero hacer es un modelo que me contenga diversas funciones, para ello quiero tener una función que me reciba dos parámetros String y otro parametro con información podría ser un arreglo

He intentado lo siguiente

```
public static function selectModel($model, $function_name, $parameters)
    {
        switch ($model) {
            case 'order':
                switch ($function_name) {
                    case 'prueba':
                        function prueba($parameters)
                {
                            $prueba = "hola";
                            return $prueba;
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        # code...
                        break;
                }

                break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    }
```

En este lo que quiero es que la función selectModel sera la que llame en mi controlador pasando como parámetros 2 string $model el cual me re dirige a un switch el cual le asigno según el modelo que estoy manejando, $function_name el cual entrara a una validación en otro switch pro siguiente que me dirige a la funcion que quiero y por ultimo se ejecuta la función que escogí y le paso los parámetros pero al realizar el return de la función recibo un mensaje de Object Object pero al hacer un var_dump en mi controlador recibo un valor null

¿Alguien sabe como hacer un método de esa manera para almacenar varios funciones o alguna manera más sencilla?

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar es mejor que crees las funciones aparte y dentro del switch es que las vas a llamar. en segundo lugar si la función no devuelve nada es porque no estas llegando a la condición que retorna algún valor, en tu caso:

```
    $prueba = "hola";
    return $prueba;
```